# MySQL: Very Slow Even After Using FORCE INDEX

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have 2 tables:
`hcpcodesdefn` about *2.5 million records*,
and `tbl_AutounbindHCPcode_valid` about *1k records*.

I need to delete the records of `hcpcodesdefn` that are existed in `tbl_AutounbindHCPcode_valid`. Columns: *hcpid* **AND** *hcpcodeid*.

I already created an SQL Index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_hcpid_hcpcodeid ON hcpcodesdefn(hcpid, hcpcodeid);
```

then executed this query:

```
DELETE FROM hcpcodesdefn FORCE INDEX(idx_hcpid_hcpcodeid)
WHERE hcpid IN (SELECT hcpid FROM tbl_AutounbindHCPcode_valid)
AND hcpcodeid IN (SELECT hcpcodeid FROM tbl_AutounbindHCPcode_valid);
```

**but still, the execution time is about 8 minutes.**

**EXPLAIN output:**

| select_type | table | type | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PRIMARY | hcpcodesdefn | ALL | 2591359 | Using where |
| DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl_AutounbindHCPcode_valid | ALL | 1028 | Using where |
| DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl_AutounbindHCPcode_valid | ALL | 1028 | Using where |

(Columns `possible_keys`, `key`, `key_len`, and `ref` are all *(NULL)*)

I tried using `INNER JOIN` but the result is not what I expected (SELECT is used, instead of DELETE to test results):

```
SELECT a.* FROM hcpcodesdefn a
INNER JOIN tbl_AutounbindHCPcode_valid b
WHERE a.hcpid = b.hcpid AND a.hcpcodeid = b.hcpcodeid;
```

*Records: 0*

**How can I optimize the performance?**

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` tell you about the usage of indices?

Comment: An equivalent JOIN needs to join `tbl_AutounbindHCPcode_valid` twice (by using an alias) -- once on `hcpid` and once on `hcpcodeid`.

Comment: *then executed this query* 1) Do you really need in a row from `hcpcodesdefn` table for which the values of `hcpid` and `hcpcodeid` were taken from different rows of `tbl_AutounbindHCPcode_valid` table? 2) Your index cannot be effectively used for this query. 3) WHERE IN is always slow, rewrite to INNER JOIN. At least.

Comment: Please add the output of `EXPLAIN` to your question, along with more details about your setup

Comment: EXPLAIN output is now added.

I tried also using INNER JOIN twice (on a.hcpid = b.hcpid ... on a.hcpcodeid = c.hcpcodeid), but still no results.

Comment: Please clean up the question -- You talk about 2 tables, yet the `DELETE` has two tables that are not in the discussion.  Furthermore, the `EXPLAIN` does not match the query.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `IN ( SELECT ... )`

Do have indexes on the other tables.

Use wither a multi-table `DELETE` with `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` or `WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ... )`